# using struct "x" that points to structs "x", to create struct "y" that points to structs "y"

Tags: c, pointers, struct, relationship

Let's say I have B+ tree nodes structured as follows:

```
typedef struct node 
{
    struct node * pointers; //pointers to child nodes
    int * keys; //keys in this node
    struct node * parent; //pointer to parent node
    bool is_leaf; //is the node a leaf
    int num_keys; //number of keys in this node
} node;
```

And a new structure, called index, with nodes structured as:

```
typedef struct index
{
    int m; //number of keys in this index
    bool flag; //does the node POINTS to a leaf
    struct index * parent_index; //pointer to parent index
    int * k; //keys in this index
    struct index * p; //pointers to child indexes
} index;
```

Let's say I input the simple keys 2, 3 and 1, on this order, to initiate and fulfill the B+ tree structure. We now made a simple B+ tree that represents our relationship between 2, 3 and 1 keys. Now I wanna copy this relationship to a new structure, which is `index`. I could navigate to each `node` of the B+ tree and make `int node->num_keys` go to `int index->m`, `bool node->is_leaf` could help fulfill `bool index->flag` with some thinking and `int * node->keys` go to `int * index->k`. As you can see, the issue starts on the remaining two pointers...
How can I possibly get a complex structure that has pointers creating a relationship between them, and copy that same relationship to a new complex structure that has the same behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You need a recursive function that clones a data structure. The general idea is each call to the recursive function duplicates one part of the complex structure, but calls a function to perform the operation on each "child" object. The special case is the function called might be itself. For your example, it might look something like:

```
node * copy_node(node *n) {
    node *r = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    r->num_keys = n->num_keys;
    r->is_leaf = n->is_leaf;
    r->keys = malloc(sizeof(int)*r->num_keys);
    r->pointers = malloc(sizeof(node *)*r->num_keys);
    for (int i=0; i<r->num_keys; i++) {
        r->keys[i] = n->keys[i];
        r->pointers[i] = copy_node(n->pointers[i]);
        r->pointers[i]->parent = r;
    }
    return r;
}
```

A similar function could be built to clone `index`.

Comment: You have some issues with the sizes you supply to `malloc()`: First `malloc()` should use `r` instead of `n` (not a bug, but not nice either). Second `malloc()` uses the size of a pointer instead of the size of an `int`. This is a bug. Best change to `sizeof(*r->keys)*num_keys`. Third `malloc()` has the same issue as the second one, and the same resolution.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm about to suggest is *very very* dodgy but, since these structs are EXACTLY the same size and all members are the same, then this deep clone could be done in place by simply reordering the members within the struct.
Any `node` pointer value is a valid `index` pointer value as long as you shuffle the members of each node to match the order an index pointer expects.

This is no doubt very bad practice, but if you can't afford mallocing that extra memory this is an option. Of course, this option is **not easily not maintainable**, as a change in the `index` definition would break the process unless a corresponding change was made to the `node` definition.